# Laravel 5.5 Real Time datatable update

Tags: laravel, socket.io

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I have implemented some datatable with DataTables.net for the view of alarms coming from the corporate network. These alarms are stored in a MySql database. I would like my tables in the blade to update automatically when a new record is stored in the table or when an update is performed. I have read several articles on the web and I think the best solution is to use the Socket.io library with laravel echo, Laravel Broadcasting and Laravel Event. But I have a question that I can't answer. How do I catch the event of a new record in the table or an update? The only way to go is to set up a trigger in the database or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database triggers aren't the only the way to catch those events. Laravel Eloquent allows you to implement hooks such as `created`, `updated`, etc...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events

Comment: Thanks. I thnk I'm going to use Laravel Eloquent. And what about Laravel Websocket instead socket.io?

Comment: I don't know Laravel Websocket, I only use Laravel Echo Server which works fine